# Google share button - custom href url

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am struggling with this one.

You would think the documentation would give your simple straight forward examples.

All I want to do is get the share button to share a custom URL, instead of the current page it's on.

Documentation here... https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/

Then this is what I've tried below and all failed...

**#1**

```
<div id="g-plus-footer" class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>

<script>
    (function() {
      var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      gapi.plus.render('g-plus-footer', {'href':'http://mysite.co.uk'});
    })();
<script>
```

**#2**

```
<div id="g-plus-footer" class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>

<script>    
    (function() {
      var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();

    gapi.plus.render('g-plus-footer', {'href':'http://mysite.co.uk'});
</script>
```

**#3**

```
<div onClick="gapi.plus.render('g-plus-footer', {'href':'http://mysite.co.uk'});" id="g-plus-footer" class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble" ></div>

<script>   
    (function() {
      var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

The error that I seem to get for all of them (apart from number 3) is...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
```

Can any one please help understand where I'm going wrong.

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Glad your question was answered. I am curious if you tried the configuration widget at the top of the page to generate your code? Welcome to receiving feedback about how to improve the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two concepts a little mixed up here, but you're on the right track.

Loading the gapi library asynchronously, which is what you're doing, will cause everything with the "g-plus" class to be rendered when it finishes loading. So you don't need to explicitly call anything.

You do, however, need to have the "data-href" attribute set on the div in question already. So you should use a tag something like

```
<div id="g-plus-footer" class="g-plus" data-href="http://example.com/" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>
```

and have the library loaded just before the closing body tag as you specify in example 3:

```
<script>   
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure to include the Google API library before referencing your `gapi`?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 // gapi should now be defined
</script>
```

You are currently loading this asynchronously, meaning that `gapi` will be undefined until the script is retrieved.  Do this synchronously and you should be good to go.

Comment: While it might solve his immediate problems, this approach can create other problems with page loading. Asnychronous loading is definitely the way to go with third party scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a `data-href` :

```
<div id="g-plus-footer" data-href="http://mysite.co.uk" class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>

<script>   
    (function() {
      var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```